# Помогите настроить шаблон c MergeField

Tags: ms-word

1. Есть шаблон в вордовском документе, в котором используются MergeField
2. Не могу понять на каком синтаксисте написан запрос, подскажите пожлст.
3. В запросе нужно реализовать условие с оператором OR

Исходный запрос:

```
«[#if classinmax2.odclass2 != '1' && classinmax2.odclass2 != '2']» см. до-полнительный лист
«[#else]»«[#list classinorder2s.classinorder2 as c»«${classinorder2.cpcclass}» 
«[/#list]»
«[#list classinorde2s.classinorde2 as cla»«${classinorde2.cpcclass}» 
«[/#list]»
 «[/#if]»
«${classinmax2.odclass2}» «${classinmax.odclass}»
```

**Что нужно**: добавить изменить скрипт так, чтобы при  classinmax2.odclass2 != '1' && classinmax2.odclass2 != '2'] **ИЛИ** classinmax.odclass != '3' выводился текст см. до-полнительный лист

4. Проблема: при **OR** вылезает ошибка, при **||** вылезает ошибка, при использовании конструкции

   #if(1)
   #if(2) см. до-полнительный лист
   #else список
   /#if(2)
   /#if(1)

срабатывает только первое условие...  и выводится пустота

Подскажите пжлст как быть, чего я не понимаю?